# How to pass a selected drop down value to a function that changes background color onclick

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick, background-color

```
<script>    
myVar = document.getElementById('colorpick').value;

function color_click(myVar){
document.getElementById("touch").style.backgroundColor=myVar;
}
</script>
<select name="colorpick" id="colorpick">
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
</select>

<div id="touch" onclick="color_click(myVar);"> XXXXXXXXXXX </div>
```

This code works as expected when I substitute 'blue' for the value of myVar, however I want to choose which color via dropdown menu before I click the element to change it's background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you want to get the color via dropdown menu when you click the div, so you need to put

```
myVar = document.getElementById('colorpick').value;
```

in the color_click function.
You can try this:

```
function color_click(){
    var myVar = document.getElementById('colorpick').value;
    document.getElementById("touch").style.backgroundColor = myVar;
}
```

And in you div:

```
<div id="touch" onclick="color_click();"> XXXXXXXXXXX </div>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the value of the selected option. To do that, you need something like this:

```
function color_click(){
    var sel = document.getElementById('colorpick'),
    myVar = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("touch").style.backgroundColor=myVar;
}
```